# How to get the Values of an given tableau of the simplex algorithm?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex, simplex-method

I have some problems with some task of an old exam and i hope u can give me a hint or a way to solve those.

Given is the tableau
$\begin{equation} 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc} 
  & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 & x_7 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A & 3 & B & C \\ \hline 
\mbox{D} & 0 & 1 & 0 & E & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 2 & F & -1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}$

And now I want to find the values of the parameters A-F so that the statements are true.

1. The first row in the present tableau indicates that the problem is infeasible.
2. The basic solution associated to B is feasible, $x_6$ is a candidate for entering the basis, and
   when $x_6$ is the entering variable, $x_3$ leaves the basis.
3. The basic solution associated to B is feasible, $x_7$ is a candidate for entering the basis, but if
   it does, the associated basic solution remains unchanged.

Comment: I think you cannot just say yes or no as an answer. So it is always a conditional answer. Are you supposed to answer just yes or no? It is also unclear if D is non-negative. Usually in a simplex table the RHS is non-negative.

Comment: @callculus No I can't I should give for every task a range for the parameters A-D e.g $A>0$. "So it is always a conditional answer" Yes there are more than one correct answer I think

Comment: @callculus Do u have any Idea how i could solve this tasks?

Comment: In my opinion your answer to 1. is fine. Maybe you should add the case where $D>0$

Comment: @callculus Thank you i will at this case too. And any hints for task 2 and 3?

Comment: It is not said if it is a maximization or a minimization problem. If the goal is to have non-positive coefficients at the objective function then B must be smaller than 0 to enter the basis. In the other case B must be greater than 3, A and C.

Comment: @callculus Ah sry  its a problem in standard form so minimize i think,means all values of the zero row should be positive to be an optimal solution